# Efficient Paste / Composite Masked Image in Pillow / Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have two png images:

heart40.png (40x40 with transparent background) -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEYof.jpg

background40.png (40x40) -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbGTI.jpg

The image is partitioned into 8x8-pixel grids and numbered from 1 --

```
---------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
---------------------
| 6 |    ...    |10 |

...

|21 |    ...    |25 |
---------------------
```

I want only selected grids, e.g., (1, 5, 8, 13, 23), from heart40.png to overlay onto the background40.png, result -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/svF5C.jpg

I'm using Pillow (don't really want to switch to another image library unless there is a show-stopper). The following code works --

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def square_id_to_xy(square_id):
    grid_count = int(40 / 8)
    y_id = ceil(square_id / grid_count)
    x_id = square_id - (grid_count * (y_id-1))
    return (x_id-1) * 8, (y_id-1) * 8


if __name__ == '__main__':
    im = Image.open("heart40.png").convert("RGBA")
    background_im = Image.open("background40.png").convert("RGBA")
    mask_im = Image.alpha_composite(background_im, im)
    show_square_ids = (1, 5, 8, 13, 23)
    for square_id in range(1, 26):
        if square_id in show_square_ids:
            continue
        x, y = square_id_to_xy(square_id)
        ImageDraw.Draw(mask_im).rectangle([(x, y), (x+7, y+7)], outline=0, fill=1)
    background_im.paste(mask_im, (0, 0), mask_im)
    background_im.save("background_pasted.png")
```

As I'm drawing transparent squares for all grids that I *do not want to show*, this can be rather inefficient when there are thousands of grids but I only want to show a few of them.

So the question is: is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Thank you Mark. I learnt something new from your answer. However, since you didn't provide a _complete answer_ and I'm too busy/lame to investigate NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR, I don't think the answer is acceptable by SO standard.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no requirement whatsoever for an answer on StackOverflow to be complete. In fact, oftentimes a hint is all that is needed to help someone out. Also, it often happens that one person can provide part of the answer and that encourages someone else who knows the other half of the answer to provide that part. Furthermore, in my estimation, my answer below is probably more thorough than 70+% of the answers you will find on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a rush, but have an idea you can maybe use, even if I don't write and test all the code...

```
grid=np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
```

will give you this:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

Then identify what you want:

```
wanted=[1,5,8,13,23]
```

and use `numpy.isin()` to test if each grid is wanted:

```
mask=np.isin(grid,wanted)
```

which gives you:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]])
```

You can now multiply that by 255 which will give you a black/white mask. You can make the mask into an image and scale it up by a factor of 5 with NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR resampling to make it the correct size.